# Display table, and strange margin in second column

Tags: css, css-tables

I have problem with table display.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
          <div class="name">
            <h4>TEST</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Opcja I</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 page">
            Why isn't it at the top?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
.col-md-2, .col-md-10 {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}  

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
  background: #DE5F4B;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar .name {
  background: #ABD173;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 36px;
}
.sidebar .name h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 120%;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.sidebar .line {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar ul.menu {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar ul.menu li {
  padding: 20px 36px;
}
.sidebar ul.menu li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*
 * Page
 */

.page {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.breadcrumb {
  background: #60BF97;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sfh23/

Why the content from of column isn't on the top?

I tried valgin-middle. border-collapse - it didn't help - nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Sfh23/2/ ?

Comment: I really can't understand what you want to achieve. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Thank you @W.D. I tried it, but i just added it in bad place.

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align:top` to `.col-md-2, .col-md-10`

```
.col-md-2, .col-md-10 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;  
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sfh23/2/)